# How can i vectorize this assignment to a structure array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, structure, vectorization

I have initialized a structure array like this:

```
[v(1:5).s] = deal( false(1, 3) );
```

Now, I would like to modify only certain elements of it.
And I can do it with a for loop, like this:

```
idv = [2 4 5];                 % v indexes
ids = [1 1 3];                 % corresponding s indexes where to write
for i=1:length(idv)
   v( idv(i) ).s( ids(i) ) = true;
end
```

Is there a way to vectorize this operation?

What if I need to update a vector inside an existing structure?

Suppose I have:

```
for i = 1:NoP
    vm(i).s = false(size(vm(i).v));
end
```

How can I vectorize this? Will I save time?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suppose your structure is more complex than your example, otherwise I do not see a reason for using it. Also, I am not aware of a more efficient way to do that and clear at the same time. The loop will definitely be hard to beat speed-wise and for clarity.

Comment: Consider switching from this array of structures to a structure of arrays. Then you can work with all the values of `s` in one array which makes your task trivial.

Comment: @OlegKomarov my structure is much more complex than this. The purpose of my question is to speed up my code.

Comment: @shoelzer I don't know how to convert this to a structure of arrays, since my actual structure is much more complex and has other fields that I omitted here.

Answer (score 1):

Simple
First we construct a cell array with the appropriate logical values

```
>> l = false(5,3);
>> l( sub2ind([5 3],idv,ids) ) = true;
>> l = mat2cell( l, ones(5,1), 3 );
```

Using this cell we can construct the struct

```
>> v = struct('s', l)
```

Comment: Could you add some timings vs the looped version?

Comment: @Shai OK, thank you. I guess it is good when initializing a structure array. What if I have to update a structure array? (see question edit)

Comment: @AlfredoCapobianchi I would recommend you look at `getfield` and `setfield` commands.